# Not retaining changes made to Values of Properties in a Custom Class

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I  created this function to remove vbCrLf from the values of properties in a Custom Class:(vTransaction)

```
Public Function ValidateTransaction(ByRef vTransaction)            
        Dim property1 As String
        Dim value1 As String

        For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In vTransaction.GetType().GetProperties()
            If p.CanRead Then
                property1 = p.Name '// FOR TESTING to identify Property Name
                value1 = p.GetValue(vTransaction, Nothing)
                If (TypeOf value1 Is String) Then
                    If value1 <> " " And value1 <> "" Then
                        'MsgBox("Before .Replace:" & vbNewLine & value1.ToString) '// FOR TESTING.
                        value1 = value1.ToString.Replace(vbCrLf, " ")
                        'MsgBox("After .Replace:" & vbNewLine & value1.ToString) '// FOR TESTING.
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Return vTransaction

    End Function
```

Throughout testing I can verify that vbCrLf is being replaced with a space as expected. When I re-examine vTransaction the changes have not been retained and the vbCrlf's are still there.

What do I need to do to retain the changes being made to values in vTransaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not setting the property value again. You are just creating a string that is not used after that. Your innermost If-block should be something like this:

```
If value1 <> " " And value1 <> "" Then
    'MsgBox("Before .Replace:" & vbNewLine & value1.ToString) '// FOR TESTING.
    p.SetValue(vTransaction, value1.ToString.Replace(vbCrLf, " "), Nothing)
    'MsgBox("After .Replace:" & vbNewLine & value1.ToString) '// FOR TESTING.
End If
```